# How to Find Whether There is a Difference in Proportion of Comments in Sentiment Analysis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, sentiment-analysis

I have two questions to solve and need your help doing this in R Studio:

1. I want to find whether there is a significant difference in the proportion of students (For Each Sentiment Analysis Classification of Positive/Neutral/Negative) between the ALC and Traditional Sections For The First Table (Classroom) and For the Second Table (Online) separately.
2. I want to find whether there is a significant difference in the proportion of students (For Each Sentiment Analysis Classification of Positive/Neutral/Negative) between The Classroom Table (First Table) and the Online Table (Second Table).

I have the two tables ready.

ALC/Trad        in_classroom    # of Students   Proportion of Students

```
ALC             Negative        20             10%
ALC             Neutral         37             18%
ALC             Positive        153            73%
Traditional     Negative        5              9%
Traditional     Neutral         11             20%
Traditional     Positive        38             70%
```

ALC/Trad          online    # of Students   Proportion of Students

```
ALC             Negative        36             14%
ALC             Neutral         89             35%
ALC             Positive        126            50%
Traditional     Negative        10             13%
Traditional     Neutral         22             29%
Traditional     Positive        44             58%
```

Any help in R Studio will be appreciated.